# bisection method in C

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods, equation, bisection

I wrote a code to find the root of a 4th degree polynom with bisection method. I wrote the same code for 3th polynom,too and that works fine. I just copy and paste, and add 4th degree term and it didn't work fine.Here is my code

```
double root4(double a0, double a1, double a2, double a3, double a4, double xs, double xe)
{
    /*0.000001 is stop point*/
    double xs_value, xe_value, stop_condition, pos_root, pos_root_val;  /*Here "y" means f(y) and pos means possible*/
    int n = 1,temp;
    do
    {
        xs_value = (a4*(xs*xs*xs*xs)) + (a3*(xs*xs*xs)) + (a2*(xs*xs)) + (a1*xs) + a0;
        xe_value = (a4*(xe*xe*xe*xe)) + (a3*(xe*xe*xe)) + (a2*(xe*xe)) + (a1*xe) + a0;
        stop_condition = (xe-xs)/(pow(2,n));
        pos_root = (xs + xe) / 2;
        pos_root_val =(a4*(pos_root*pos_root*pos_root*pos_root))+(a3*(pos_root*pos_root*pos_root))+(a2*(pos_root*pos_root))+(a1*pos_root)+a0;
        if(xs_value * pos_root_val < 0)
            xe = pos_root;
        if(xe_value * pos_root_val < 0)
            xs = pos_root;      
        n++;
    }
    while(stop_condition >= 0.000001);
    return pos_root;
}
```

When I give these values

```
root4(1,10,7,3,-4,-50,50)); last two number means interval like [-50,50]
```

It gives me

```
0.000000
```

And when I change interval as [-50,51] outbut becomes 0.500000
I think problem is about boundaries but as I said, it works fine for 3th degree polynom.

Comment: have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. It also helps if you split up complex expressions into smaller and simpler expressions, to see if the intermediate results are valid and as expected. For example, `(a2*(xs*xs)` could be `double t1 = xs * xs; double t2 = a2 * t1;` and so on.

Comment: No, I'm just using terminal in Ubuntu, no ide so no debug,but when it compiles it's okey

Comment: The standard debugger in Linux is the comma-line based `gdb`. On Linux that's usually what most IDE's are using anyway. Learning how to use a debugger is among the most important and crucial parts of programming.

Comment: You can always debug with `printf`.

Comment: Note that in this particular case, you get a good result with `else if(xe_value * pos_root_val < 0)`,  because by chance the central point has a `y` positive value.

Comment: Criticism of your code: 1) it is a sin to recompute three polynomial values on every iteration; 2) it is a deadly sin to compute a polynomial without the Horner's scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Your polynomial looks like this (note that the y-axis is scaled down A LOT):

[image]

In particular, the function is negative on both sides of the interval. In order for the bisection method to converge to a root, the function must be positive on one side of the interval and negative on the other. For 3rd degree (or any odd degree) polynomials, this is always the case if you take a big enough interval. For 4th degree (or any even degree) this is exactly the opposite.

The bottom line is that this is not an error in your algorithm. It's just the initial conditions you give it that are bad.

Comment: This gives me an idea, I can divide intervals into two if it contains zero and my problem will be solved. Thanks for help!